# docker volume: subdirectories are missing

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm using docker native on a mac (1.13.1, latest) and want to mount a volume into my docker container, however, the content of the mounted volume is only showing two hierarchy levels downwards:

```
docker run -i -t \
    --name container \
    -v /Users/xxx/mount/share:/share \
    $imageid \
    /bin/bash -i
```

the source data has a hierarchy structure like so:

```
+ share
|___dir1
   |__ subdir1
      |__ abc (missing)
      |__ abc2 (missing)
   |__ subdic2
      |__ abc (missing)
      |__ abc2 (missing)
|__ dir2
  file1.txt (missing)
```

The problem is that everything below subdir1 is not there, ie. the folders are empty.

Is this a limitation of docker? Do I have to mount the volumes differently?

Thank you in advance

fabian

Comment: Is this the complete command you're using? Are there VOLUMEs defined in your Dockerfile as well? The only thing I can think of is that other volumes mounted at e.g. `/share/dir1/subdir1` and similar are over-riding parts of the volume mount you have shown here. Including your Dockerfile would be helpful.

Comment: hey, thank you very much for the quick reply. You are right, the problem was the inheritance of a parent container: I created a VOLUME in the parent container and tried to override it in the child container.